# Tachanun at Mincha afternoon before Yom Yerushalem

Tags: tachanun, mincha-afternoon-prayer, yom-yerushalayim

For those who celebrate Yom Yerushalem,is Tachanun said during Mincha the afternoon before Yom Yerushalem?

Comment: I assume that this is asking only according to those who don't say _tachanun on Yom Y'rushalayim_. If so, you might want to clarify that in the question.

Comment: @msh210 Given the current state of the question, one valid answer is "Many Jews don't celebrate Y"Y. For them, Tachanun is said at Mincha the day before."

Comment: @IsaacMoses, fair enough. (Well, "don't celebrate with the omission of _tachanun_" anyway.)

Comment: Some say no, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/103534/11501

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The days that we do say tachanun at Mincha, even though we don't say tachanun the next morning are Erev Rosh Hashanah, and Erev Yom Kippur, and there's a dispute (in both the Ashkenazi and Sephardi spheres) about Pesach Sheni. Neither of these are "real holidays" in the same sense that Purim and Chanukah are.

Since I would think that Yom Yerushalyim and Yom HaAtzmaut are supposed to be similar to Chanukah and Purim, it seems to be reasonable that if you omit tachanun on Yom Yerushalyim or Yom HaAtzmaut, then you should omit tachanun at Mincha the day before also.

(No sources, just my sevara here. Consult your rabbi for a precise ruling.)

Comment: If anyone has a copy of the siddur [Go'el Yisrael](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/goel/sidur.htm) put out by the Hesder yeshiva in Ramat Gan, according to [this](http://www.aishdas.org/avodah/vol15/v15n013.shtml#02), it seems like it would have relevant information. (The page he quotes is not included in the free pdf.)

Comment: Not only that, I davened mincha yesterday at a shul that omitted tachanun because it was the mincha before Yom Yerushalyim. (I didn't realize why they omitted it until now.)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43404&st=&pgnum=130

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43404&st=&pgnum=131

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43404&st=&pgnum=132

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43404&st=&pgnum=133

You do not say Tachanun at Mincha the day prior to a day that you do not say Tachanun other than if there is a specific reason to - see links above

If you do not say Tachnun on Yom Yerushalayim as some people do then you would not say it at Mincha the day before either.

Comment: Source, please?

Comment: In the Halachos of Tachanun you never say Tachanun at Mincha on a day prior which you do not say Tachanun.

Comment: According to the ArtScroll _sidurim_, some do at the _mincha_ before _lag baomer_ or _pesach sheni_ (I forget which).

Comment: Also, no tachanun on erev rosh hashana and erev yom kippur, but yes tachanun on mincha of the days before.

Comment: @jake: practically, some do say tachanun on erev Rosh Hashanah and erev Yom Kippur (in the morning selichot) and hence it would indeed be appropriate to say tachanun the mincha before according to the general rule

Comment: @Curiouser, Yes. When I was in yeshiva, I was the baal tefilla once for the mincha before erev R"H, and I skipped tachanun going straight to kaddish, thinking the "mincha-before" rule was always true. The rabbi came up to the amud after kaddish to inform me of my mistake and the yeshiva had to go back and say tachanun. It was a little embarrassing on my part. The way he explained it to me, though, was that erev R"H only becomes a "non-tachanun" day after selichos in the morning, which is why people will still say the tachanun in the selichos.

Answer (score 1):

Explicit instructions are given in the Rinat Yisrael siddur, widely used in Israel:

> במנחה שלפניו אין אומרים תחנון, ואם חל בשבת אין אומרים צדקתך.
>
> At mincha before it tachanun is not said, and if it is Shabbat, tzidkatcha is not said. (translation mine)

You can view this on [Hebrewbooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34229&st=&pgnum=463&hilite=).