# Tachanun during the mincha before a bris

Tags: brit-milah, tachanun

According to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8005/1362) answer (and a number of other discussions on the web) one does not say tachanun during the mincha on the day before the relevant simcha-day.

Would this include a case where a baby is scheduled to have a bris the next morning?

[this then begs a question regarding the "simcha" vs. "kedusha" of the day of a bris so I can consider whether a month with 15 bris days would obviate tachanun on the rest of the days]

Comment: OC is quite explicit by saying _on the day_ https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_אורח_חיים_קלא_ד

Comment: I haven't read the above source to remind me. But, I think that one could say that there's a big difference between a Yom Tobv which is a day that is a simcha for everyone vs. a Brit that is a simcha that applies only to the shul and the people davening in it that day. But what is more curious with the brit, is that, IIRC, the morning brit in the shul exempts the cong. from Tachanun during mincha of the same day even though the brit has occurred. But, it doesn't affect the mincha of the prior day. I guess it has something to do with it being a different day that is not the date of the brit.

Comment: @DanF that brings up another question as to whether the simcha is for the shul or the community. Can I go shul to shul looking for a bris so I can avoid tachanun or is it for those who are part of that community who can share the joy?

Comment: @rosends It seems to be for the whole synagogue: http://ph.yhb.org.il/02-21-08/

Comment: @rosends "Can I go shul to shul looking for a bris so I can avoid tachanun ". Funny you should ask ... Recently, Rabbi Pesach Krohn, a "famous" mohel told me that he tells people, "Don't want to say Tachanun, today? Follow me!" He was joking, but, technically, one can absolutely do that, and in reality, people do it, at least in my neighborhood. I've heard of someone who posts a weekly listing of neighborhood shuls he knows will have a brit or chattan, etc. for those who want to avoid Tachanun. So, yes, it works, but it's not an "ethical" thing to do.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I know it is for the shul (even other minyanim that day) but I wonder if they are still part of a "community" as opposed to the guy from 10 miles away who wants to avoid davening and doesn't know anyone.

Comment: Supposedly, "everyone" is "invited" to a brit. Rav Binyamin Kamenetzky, zt"l told me that this is one of the reasons why the parents never extend a "formal" invitation to anyone. It's understood that you should come! Rav Kamentezky would attend any brit in his neighborhood even if he had never heard of the family before. In his case, he wanted to share in the simcha and encourage the parents to send their boy to his yeshiva!